# Read Xbox Music playlist file

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-phone-8.1, xbox-music

I plan to develop music player for Windows Phone 8.1 and I'd like to read the playlists created through Xbox Music player or through PC app. The playlist files are stored in hidden folder Playlists in Music folder but those files empty and contain special tab 'References' when looking on their properties that contains names of songs included in playlist.

I have not found any source of information how to read this type of file.

Picture showing references tab in the Properties window
[image: Picture showing references tab in the Properties window]

The file has no extension and 0 bytes.

How do I access the data shown on the references tab in my .NET application?

Comment: If the file had any content I would try to parse it but the file is empty (0 bytes). It has no extension and all I found is that it should be .pla file extension but everything I found about this extension is that it is used by CAD systems. Asking on stackoverflow is the last on my list of ways to find solution to my problem.

Comment: I personally have not seen the references tab like that and I didn't see any obvious way to access that data when I looked at the  [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class. So I'm very curious what the answer to this turns out to be. If you don't get an answer in a couple of days, ping me by using the `@Mason` syntax in a comment and I'll open a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question, which should attract some responses.

Comment: This is visible only when I plug my WP and check properties of the file while it's still on my phone. As soon as I copy the file elsewhere it is just empty file without any special tabs.